# If the integral of a $k$ form over any $k$ chain is $0$ then the differential form itself is $0$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Let $\omega$ be a $k$ form on an open set $A\subseteq \mathbb R^n$ such that for any $k$-chain $c$ in $A$ , $\int_c \omega =0$ , then is it true that $\omega =0$ ?

Comment: I think is wrong integrate a k-1 form over a k-chain. Do you mean $$\int_c\mbox{d}\omega=0?$$

Comment: @DiegoMath : oh sorry , I have corrected it

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's true. First, remember how you would show this when $k=n$. Given the $n$-form $\omega = f(x)dx_1\wedge\dots\wedge dx_n$, if $\omega$ is not everywhere zero, there is a point $a$ with $f(a)\ne 0$, say $f(a)>0$. By continuity, we choose a neighborhood $U$ of $a$ and choose an $n$-chain $\Delta\subset U$. Then $\int_\Delta \omega >0$, contradicting the hypothesis.

The same idea works for general $k$. Write $\omega = \sum\limits_{I \text{ increasing}} f_I dx_I$. Suppose $f_I(a)>0$ for some point $a$, and choose a $k$-chain $\Delta$ contained in $U\cap \Bbb R^I$.

Comment: I don't understand the last two lines of your reply. Are we supposing $f_I (a)>0$ for all multi-indices $I$? How can we do this? This doesn't to my understanding follow from $\omega(a) \neq 0$.

Comment: No, no. I didn't say "for all $I$." Since $\omega(a)\ne 0$, there is (at least) one multi-index $I$ with $f_I(a)\ne 0$. The sign is actually not too relevant.

Comment: Alright, but now if say $f_I(a)>0$ and $f_J(a)<0$ then can't the two cancel each other out in the integral $\int_\Delta \omega$, yielding zero?

Comment: Not if you pick the chain as I prescribed!

Comment: Ah I see, is it here that $\mathbb{R}^I$ with $I=(i_1,...,i_k)$ is the set of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ with $x^i=0$ for $i\neq i_1,...,i_k$? Sorry I'm new to differential geometry, thanks for the replies.